# Excel run macro only if active cell in correct column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table called Sales with a column called Supplier, I want the user to select a supplier and click a button to run a macro but only if the active cell is in the Supplier column. The code I current have is below but it uses the whole column how can I change it so it refers to the Supplier table range only.

```
If Activecell.Column = 7 then

....

Else

...

End if
```

Comment: The seventh column n the **work sheet** or the seventh column in the **Table** (they may not be the same)

Comment: It was the column in the worksheet, also happens to be the seventh column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
 If Intersect(ActiveCell, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
      // cell not in table
   Else
      // cell in table
   End If
```

Comment: This looks like it tests only whether the active cell is in the table, not whether it is in the correct column.

Comment: Oh yes, try ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(7).DataBodyRange. Also have a look here how to address different parts of a table in VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541445/select-entire-column-in-table-using-excel-vba/43541508